# wrap_content leaving extra white space at bottom of screen for ViewPager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jK3BZ.png)

`Wrap_content` inside 2nd `linearlayout` leaving the extra white space at bottom of screen but if give hardcoded value it's working fine. any issue with `wrap_content` ? Here I am using this .xml on `viewPager` anyone have idea about this issue.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/white_noround">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/canceledPesananTgl"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="ABCDEFGHI"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="#999999"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="-15dp"
                    android:text="29 JAN 2016"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="#999999"
                    android:id="@+id/canceledDate"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="visible"
                >
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/image_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight=".9"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="80dp"
                            android:layout_height="80dp"
                            android:id="@+id/canceled_dummuyImage1"
                            android:background="@drawable/imageview_border"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:src="@drawable/empty_photo"/>
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="90dp"
                            android:layout_height="90dp"
                            android:id="@+id/canceled_dummuyImage2"
                            android:background="@drawable/imageview_border"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:src="@drawable/empty_photo"/>
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="110dp"
                            android:layout_height="110dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/imageview_border">
                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="90dp"
                                android:layout_height="90dp"
                                android:id="@+id/canceledImage"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/empty_photo"/>
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_weight=".4"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp">
                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="horizontal">
                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:orientation="vertical"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:text="SONY Memory Card Playstation 2"
                                        android:textSize="16sp"
                                        android:id="@+id/productName"
                                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                                        android:textColor="#333333"/>
                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                                        android:id="@+id/productStatus"
                                        android:textSize="14dp"
                                        android:text="Dalam pengiriman"
                                        android:textStyle="normal"
                                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                                        android:textColor="#f7931e"/>
                                </LinearLayout>
                            </RelativeLayout>
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `wrap_content` means it sets hight or width of view according to content of its child. you are setting hight of your `LinearLayout` to `wrap_content` so it measures its child's hight and wrap according to it.

Comment: @vrundpurohit For second LinearLayout if I give 50dp instead of android:layout_height="wrap_content" then it's throwing extra white space.

Comment: Any reason why It is like that

Comment: I have attached image also U will find that

Comment: @vrundpurohit For second LinearLayout if I give android:layout_height="wrap_content" instead of 50dp  then it's throwing extra white space .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was doing with above .xml was to populate list of items using listView on ViewPager. So the above .xml is listItem .xml so we should always go with below code.This line worked for me android:layout_height="wrap_content".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/white_noround"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is here. see this Parent LinearLayout.

```
 <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight=".4"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp">
```

In this You have used `android:paddingBottom="10dp"` so the child' element work fine but The Extra white Space is for it's parent layout to Solve your problem remove `android:paddingBottom="10dp"` line.

Comment: It's not working after removing the android:paddingBottom="10dp line

Comment: @VinodPattanshetti after remove that what you get trouble.

Comment: same it's leaving extra white space at bottom of scree, after every scroll this white space is increasing.

Comment: @VinodPattanshetti add your full Screen shot so i can better understand.

Comment: @VinodPattanshetti and also In Screen shot show your problem by marker .

Comment: Inside that image u can find gray extra white space at middle of screen.

Comment: @VinodPattanshetti add the layout of gray white space below.

Comment: I didn't get u, What I have to do??? what is add the layout of gray white space below?????

Comment: @VinodPattanshetti Add full Layout of your Activity.

Comment: @VinodPattanshetti add  `android:fitsSystemWindows="true" ` in your LinearLayout.

Comment: Actually this is .xml file I am using for adapter and I am setting this adapter on ViewPager.

Comment: @VinodPattanshetti try to use upper property in LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="visible"
                >
```

in the above linear layout instead of layout_height as 150dp try giving wrap_content